# Hide Shipping Carrier Depending on Location

Tags: expresso-store, shipping, checkout, ups-shipping

Currently my store has two shipping carriers (UPS and the Default Shipping Plugin - called Speed-ee). For the default shipping plugin I only want to use it for four or five US states. For all others states, as well as Canada, I want to use UPS.

Is there a way to show the default shipping plugin option only when the billing address is from those four or five states and hide it if they are shipping to other areas?

I would think a conditional might work but I don't really know where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write a conditional as you have mentioned, it would need to be similar to [this conditional](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11456/international-shipping-conditional-in-exp-store) but if you only have 2 shipping options you could actually use a hidden field instead of a select element.